# What is the true meaning of the pendant which Gunzou Chihaya buys for Iona in town?

Tags: arpeggio-of-blue-steel

In the movie *Aoki Hagane no Arpeggio: Ars Nova Cadenza*, at 38:30 mark, Iona got attracted to a pendant in shop.

[image: pendant]

... which lead to another event where Iona met Musashi.

[image: Musashi]

I, myself, feel that these events are so connected. Going to town, the pendant,  Musashi. However, I have no clue why.

Could anyone provide me with solid argument and evidence?